# Clarity Datagrid: Is there a recommended way to disable animations when expanding a row?

Tags: clarity, vmware-clarity

I'm trying to use Clarity datagrid with expandable rows:
https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/datagrid/expandable-rows

While the animation when expanding a row manually is nice, I have a use case in which I need to render the grid with all rows expanded or with just some of them expanded. In this case the animation is annoying and causes unnecessary flickering. Is there a recommended way to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

Pre-expanded rows with

```
<clr-dg-row-detail *clrIfExpanded="true">
```

or

```
<clr-dg-row-detail *clrIfExpanded="item.expanded">
```

do not animate: https://plnkr.co/edit/iwrxr80RphYLn96vb2qk?p=preview

You should update your question with an example, because based on my plunker you don't need to disable animations in your case.